# O nation prove with limit theroem?

Tags: recurrence-relation, landau-notation

I'm working on my school homework,even though i found all three of these. It says use limit to compare. I confused , what should i do, i mean its obvious C A B

[image]

[image]

Comment: "use limit" means try to compare for example between $T_A$ and $T_B$ by the following: $\lim_{n->\infty}\frac{T_A}{T_B}$ if they goes to 0, then $T_B$ grows faster, then A is more efficient than B. If they goes to infinity, then this means that $T_A$ grows faster than B and thus B is more efficient than A. By this, you "prove it". Of course as question says in its hints, it is easy to use master theorem directly.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it. Assuming you tried to solve it yourself and got stuck, it may be helpful if you wrote your thoughts and what you could not figure out. It will definitely draw more answers to your post. Until then, the question will be voted to be closed / downvoted. You may also want to check out [these hints](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98), or use the search engine of this site to find similar questions that were already answered.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!